# Can CiviCrm be used for membership and financial management?

Tags: civicontribute, evaluating-civicrm

***Can it be used for the following ?***

each month a paper document is submitted to the Head Office of the non-profit; attendance, donations, finance. User wants all this to be submitted as a softcopy.

Currently data on the non profit is stored in the cabinet room but there is no database that allows convenient access to the data, i.e. allow access from all locations with internet connection. User wants all this data to be a conveniently accessed database.

***Here are some additional responsibilities of the finance department***

Maintain financial records,
organize and reconcile weekly collections, expenses, and receipt payments.
High level budgeting and comparing the budget with the actual financial condition of the nonprofit

***The financial controllers wants the following***

Identify who is sending the money
pay salaries electronically
Search function to find WHO is paying WHAT, and HOW much was paid.

The system must be able to sync all the departments, especially  the financial department so that any change;  deletion, addition,  or minimal adjustment to the data is seen by all and is accessed by all.

At core the software must be a collaborative instrument to help sections of a company operate well, and help companies in dissimilar locations behavior as If they are in the same location working on the same task in the same room with the same tools

Comment: Can someone point me to documentation for integration with Xero?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use an accounting system such as Xero which has integration with CiviCRM to fully achieve the goals.

You can find some documentation about the integration [here](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/civicrm-integration-xero) and [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/civicrm-xero-accounting-package-integration-a-bit-of-a-look)

Comment: CiviCRM is a CRM not an accounting system.      CiviCRM does very little of the tasks that you have listed for the finance dept.  The financial controllers will only be able to use Civi to identify who is contributing the money.     It will allow multiple users to access and edit the information--donor contacts, giving, communication, etc.    But they will (not may) need something different to handle the accounting.

Comment: @CarlMiller, have you looked at the Financial Accounts and Quickbooks integration in CiviCRM? This is an area that I'd like to explore more myself but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes because I support at least one organization that's been using for such purposes for nearly 7 years and several others for 3 - 5 years. This is one of the core features of CiviCRM and it's been getting better at it over the years. Whoever is in charge of this endeavour will need to learn how the contributions system within CiviCRM works and how it relates to Memberships, Events, etc and how to run reports but it is definitely all there.

EDIT: This is the Financial Accounts area of a recent build (there is a substantial learning curve).

[image: Financial Accounts]

Comment: I  am not sure about the expense management part. There is no real cost recording functionality in civicrm at least I am not aware of.